# How to find the logs for a call for a certain time period

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am working on configuring a StackDriver alert, and we need to filter a log metric to only find logs for an hour at a time, and I just haven't found much online.

So far this is what we have for the metric in GCP:

```
resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.module_id="some_service"
logName:"log_url_here"
protoPayload.resource: "task"
```

Just curious if there's a way to filter from an hour ago, to now at all times.